# How to set up notifications in ActiveMQ Artemis when DLQ.t24TWSQueue came or t24TWSQueue receives more than four messages

Tags: activemq-artemis

If the `t24TWSQueue` has received more than four messages, and those four messages are still in the process in the app server with a Delivering count, we want to receive a notification. How can we configure this in ActiveMQ Artemis? We are considering using either Grafana or SolarWinds.

And in case those message not process it will sent to `DLQ.t24TWSQueue` and we need set notification in case `DLQ.t24TWSQueue` Queue received also

Kindly provide suggestions, as this is crucial for our operations. Below attached the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ Artemis itself won't send you notifications about arbitrary events you are concerned with for your use-case. However, you can configure a [metrics plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html#metrics) (e.g. [this Prometheus implementation](https://github.com/jbertram/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin)) which can integrate with a provider that has this functionality. For example, you can expose metrics with the Prometheus metrics plugin, scrape them with Prometheus, and then integrate Grafana for dashboards and alerts. Of course, you'd need to work with the Prometheus and Grafana communities if you have any problems or questions with them.

Comment: Do we have any excellent pre defined dashboard for artemis in grafana ? plz

Comment: Try https://github.com/artemiscloud/grafana.